# Why would $this->data show up an empty array after submit?

Tags: php, security, cakephp, components

In Cakephp Why would $this->data show up an empty array after submit? i am using the security component.

Comment: It would be good  if you can give us some code.. And why did you mention the security component?

Answer (score 1):

$this->data would be empty if nothing had been submitted during a post action from a form in most cases.

If in doubt, make sure that debug is 2 in your app/config/core.php and then

```
pr($this)
```

Which will show you everything in the app, and you can see if anything is missing. Unforunatly, with such a vague question, it's hard to give you a concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there're something wrong with your form.